# How can I call keyDown event by passing arguments, Winforms Vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio

The Following is a combo box keydown event

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.KeyDown
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
            TextBox2.Text = ComboBox1.Text
            TextBox2.Focus()
        End If
    End Sub
```

I would like to trigger same event from combobox_leave by passing 'enter key' I did as follows but not working, how to achieve this?

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Leave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.Leave
    ComboBox1_KeyDown(Me, Keys.Enter)
End Sub
```

Comment: @user17777733 try extracting the process from the keydown event

Comment: Just curious, why do you want to punish your users with a non-standard behavior of their keyboard? After the initial surprise they will be mad at you when they discover that you doesn't allow to set the focus to another control. My advice: if you don't have a really valid reason do not mess with the system keyboard handler and the focus events

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just extract the method from the actual event?

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.KeyDown
    performAction(e.KeyCode);
End Sub

Private Sub performAction(e as Keys)
    If e = Keys.Enter Then
        TextBox2.Text = ComboBox1.Text
        TextBox2.Focus()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_Leave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.Leave
    performAction(Keys.Enter);
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks, can u remove semi column and add end sub, its VB... :)

Comment: i solved my prob, can't achieve this using separate sub routine?

Comment: @user1777733 you can achieve what you initially wanted but that'd be too complex than just invoking it from another method.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the [SendKeys.Send](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send(v=vs.110).aspx) Method

When the user leaves the Combobox (like in your example),

You could set back the Focus to the combobox

and then use `SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}")` to trigger the enter keydown.

much like this:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Leave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.Leave
        
        ComboBox1.Focus()
        SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}")
End Sub
```

However this prevents users from focusing to another component. To prevent this, you could use an `if statement` that if the user clicks or focuses on another component after focusing on the combobox, the user can still "leave" the combobox.

Your kind of approach is not advisable and this leads to a misunderstanding in the part of the user.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As
keyEventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.KeyDown
    Dim _KeyCode As Short
    If e Is Nothing Then
        _KeyCode = 13
    Else
        _KeyCode = Keys.Enter
    End If

    If _KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        TextBox2.Text = ComboBox1.Text
        TextBox2.Focus()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_Leave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)  
Handles ComboBox1.Leave
Dim keypress As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs
    ComboBox1_KeyDown(sender, keypress)
End Sub
```